# how to deny access files from outside in php server?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this problem in my .htaccess file
this is my .htaccess file

```
# enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# RewriteCond = define rule condition
# HTTP_REFERER = check from where the request originated
# ! = exclude
# ^ = start of string
# [NC] = case insensitive search
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost/mywebsit/filemanager/index.php [NC]
# \ = match any
# . = any character
# () = pattern, group
# $ = end of string

# [F] = forbidden, 403
# [L] = stop processing further rules
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
```

this code deny to access to or download any files from url, but it allows you to access the files from the index.php

now the problem is when i open the terminal in the first laptop with the ip address 192.168.1.11 and write this code

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and run it
when i bring my other laptop and type this

```
192.168.1.11:8000/filemanager/files/worddoc.doc
```

the files downloads normally

so what shout i do to prevent downloading the files in this case??

Comment: If they're accessible from a link in a web page then they're accessible via any other kind of http request, there's no difference.

Comment: I see you're trying to restrict access based on the Referer header, but that is a) optional, b) not very reliable and c) easily spoofed. It can't provide any real security.

Comment: they are accessible from this link
192.168.1.11:8000/filemanager/files/worddoc.doc
but not from this link
localhost/filemanager/files/worddoc.doc

Comment: That might be more to do with the bindings of the webserver. I've just realised you're using the PHP built-in webserver, so it won't be doing anything with your htaccess file anyway - you'd have to use Apache if you want to test that. But like I said the use of referer is not going to be very effective or secure.

Comment: 100% to what @ADyson said. .htaccess is an Apache-only thing, other servers such as Nginx, IIS and PHP’s built-in server don’t understand it, just as only IIS only knows what a web.config is.

Comment: so any suggestion to solve this problem with a way or another??

Comment: Yes, the suggestion is to use Apache if you want to use the htaccess. Other than that, if you want to restrict access to your files, then either a) if you want to restrict access to only one particular machine then use IP blocking. Or b) if you want to restrict access only to certain people then use authentication (i.e. username and password). Both can be configured through Apache / htaccess settings if you like, or there are other ways to do it. Do some research.

Comment: Thank you so much
But how can i open a server using apache?
something similar to php -S 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: No, you run Apache as a service, so it's always on. then you tell it (via its configuration file) which folder to serve the files on. P.s. you could have found that out yourself easily with a bit of basic research online....